# TeamViewer не подключается

Tags: teamviewer

На удаленном рабочем столе (сервере) установил teamviewer, если соединение с сервером активно (например зашел через свой пк), то и teamviewer подключается к серверу, если нет активного соединения, то не подключается, выдает ошибку, что у партнера скорее всего нет подключения к интернету. Кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: по ощущениям - это бага, иногда проявляется а ингода нет (сам периодически ловлю, решения не нашел) одно могу сказать - у меня такое только с рабочим компом

Comment: то есть при подключении к серверу, пропадает интернет на том пк с которого подключались?

Comment: нет, при подключении к удаленной машине пишет что у партнера отсутствует подключение, хотя в списке активных компьютеров она есть

Comment: скорее всего stun определяет ваши компы в одной подсети.

Comment: как такое может быть? они не в одной подсети